# Supabase login error: auth.signIn is not a function

Tags: javascript, api, authentication, supabase

I am trying to log in via Supabase and get the error:

```
react_devtools_backend.js:2655 Error: _supabaseClient__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.default.auth.signIn is not a function
overrideMethod @ react_devtools_backend.js:2655
handleLogin @ AuthModal.js:38
onSubmit @ AuthModal.js:77
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4164
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:4213
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4277
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @ react-dom.development.js:4291
executeDispatch @ react-dom.development.js:9041
processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder @ react-dom.development.js:9073
processDispatchQueue @ react-dom.development.js:9086
dispatchEventsForPlugins @ react-dom.development.js:9097
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:9288
batchedUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:26140
batchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:3991
dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem @ react-dom.development.js:9287
dispatchEventWithEnableCapturePhaseSelectiveHydrationWithoutDiscreteEventReplay @ react-dom.development.js:6465
dispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:6457
dispatchDiscreteEvent @ react-dom.development.js:6430
```

The documentation says that that is in fact a function and I am using code very similar to it to sign up and the sign up code works just fine.

Here is my code:

```
const email = useRef();
  const password = useRef();


  const handleLogin = async (email, password) => {

    try {
      const { user, error } = await supabase.auth.signIn({
        email: email,
        password: password,
      })
      if (error) {
        if (error.message === 'Email not confirmed') {
          setError('Please check your email and confirm your address before logging in.');
        } else {
          console.error('Error during sign in:', error.message);
        }
      } else {
        console.log('User signed in:', user);
        onLogin(); // Call the onLogin prop here
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error:', error.message);
    }
  };
```

[Here is the documentation:](https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/v1/auth-signin)

```
const { user, session, error } = await supabase.auth.signIn({
  email: 'example@email.com',
  password: 'example-password',
})
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I was using v1 docs but v2 supabase.

Changing supabase.auth.SignIn to

supabase.auth.SignInWithPassword

fixed it.